# Should I also store fetched data local in my app?

Tags: ios, mysql, local-storage

I'm making an iOS app where I fetch data from a MySQL database via a web API (in JSON format). When I load a specific screen the first time should I always save the fetched data local or it is okay that I fetched the data again when the app opens again from being closed/killed? My app has a login in module so right now I only store the current users information local. I also fetch images but those I cache.

Comment: Depend on your application. If the data is like it to be static or not. That can save a lot of bandwidth.

You can save data with version and check with server version before start to trigger new downloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking whether to cache the information you download from an API or toss it and grab new every time? This is a very opinionated answer, but to me, it depends on how often the information you're fetching updates or changes itself. Do your users expect to see totally different information every time the app loads? If yes, maybe you don't need to bother caching. The Facebook app, after being killed, opens to a pulsating loading newsfeed. The twitter app, on the other hand, shows you the most recent tweets it loaded then shows an inline notification that more tweets have loaded and you should scroll up to read them. There's no right or wrong answer, it's really up to you.